# Kantlipsum installation process

Tags: packages

Why for the [`kantlipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/kantlipsum) package the process below is required to install it, instead of the normal positioning of the file `.sty` like for the other packages? Are there some advantages?

```
To install the distribution:

 - run "latex kantlipsum.ins"
 - move "kantlipsum.sty" to locations where LaTeX will find it (the FAQ on CTAN in 
   /help/uktug-FAQ gives more information about this magic place)
```

Update:

For example the package [`classicthesis`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) provides directly the `.sty` file without run

```
"latex <file>.ins"
```

Comment: That is the normal procedure: could you explain what you think is different?

Comment: Moreover, it's easiest to install the package using the package manager for your distribution ([`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) for [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) and MPM for [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/)).

Comment: The package is still not updated in TeX Live, but the version on CTAN is the new one. The standard instruction in the README file are for manual installation, but of course it's easier to wait for it being updated in the main distributions.

Comment: @JosephWright I have updated the question...

Comment: @FormlessCloud: Many packages provide different ways of manual installation. Some provide a fully-functioning `.sty`, while others provide a `.ins`/`.dtx` pair. Under Windows/MiKTeX, see [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/5764) However, you could also read [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764) which localizes the "installation" of the package. Once it forms part of the default distribution, you should remove it from the local tree.

Answer (score 2):

From the README file found at the location in CTAN:

```
To install the distribution:

o run "latex kantlipsum.ins"
o move "kantlipsum.sty" to locations where LaTeX will find
  it (the FAQ on CTAN in /help/uktug-FAQ gives more
  information about this magic place
```

Comment: Enrico, this is already quoted in the question. The OP wants to know _why_ he/she needs to do it. I think, Werner’s comment is the right answer here.

Answer (score 0):

CTAN supports the hierarchy `CTAN:install/...` that contain `.tds.zip` files for packages that provide this kind of archives, including `kantlipsum`:

[CTAN:install/macros/latex/contrib/kantlipsum.tds.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/kantlipsum.tds.zip)

Such a `.tds.zip` file can easily unzipped in the home or local `texmf` tree, because
the package is already unpacked, the documentation generated and the files sorted into the right directories according to [TDS (A Directory Structure for TeX Files](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/tds/tds.pdf):

```
Archive:  kantlipsum.tds.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  10-15-12 01:23   doc/
        0  10-15-12 01:23   doc/latex/
        0  10-15-12 01:23   doc/latex/kantlipsum/
   429153  10-15-12 01:23   doc/latex/kantlipsum/kantlipsum.pdf
     1158  10-15-12 01:23   doc/latex/kantlipsum/README
        0  10-15-12 01:23   source/
        0  10-15-12 01:23   source/latex/
        0  10-15-12 01:23   source/latex/kantlipsum/
   198687  10-15-12 01:23   source/latex/kantlipsum/kantlipsum.dtx
      856  10-15-12 01:23   source/latex/kantlipsum/kantlipsum.ins
        0  10-15-12 01:23   tex/
        0  10-15-12 01:23   tex/latex/
        0  10-15-12 01:23   tex/latex/kantlipsum/
   189723  10-15-12 01:23   tex/latex/kantlipsum/kantlipsum.sty
 --------                   -------
   819577                   14 files
```

Therefore there is no need for `kantlipsum` for providing a `.sty` file, because it is already done in a way that is much easier for the user, if he wants to install
the package.

Comment: This holds for `kantlipsum`, because I provide a `.tds.zip` file; however this is not a general rule: it's not required to upload the `.tds.zip` file and it won't be built automatically.